# extract partial string based on pattern in r

Tags: regex, r

I would like to extract partial string from a list. I don't know how to define the pattern of the strings. Thank you for your helps.

```
library(stringr)
names = c("GAPIT..flowerdate.GWAS.Results.csv","GAPIT..flwrcolor.GWAS.Results.csv",
"GAPIT..height.GWAS.Results.csv","GAPIT..matdate.GWAS.Results.csv")
# I want to extract out "flowerdate", "flwrcolor", "height" and "matdate"
traits <- str_extract_all(string = files, pattern = "..*.")
# the result is not what I want.
```

Comment: `.` is a regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few solutions. The first two do not use regular expressions at all. The lsat one uses a single `gsub`:

**1) read.table**. This assumes the desired string is always the 3rd field:

```
read.table(text = names, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE)[[3]]
```

**2) strsplit**  This assumes the desired string has more than 3 characters and is lower case:

```
sapply(strsplit(names, "[.]"), Filter, f = function(x) nchar(x) > 3 & tolower(x) == x)
```

**3) gsub**  This assumes that two dots preceed the string and one dot plus junk not containing two successive dots comes afterwards:

```
gsub(".*[.]{2}|[.].*", "", names)
```

**REVISED** Added additional solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `regmatches`

```
> regmatches(c, regexpr("[[:lower:]]+", c))
[1] "flowerdate" "flwrcolor"  "height"     "matdate"
```

I encourage you not to use `c` as a variable name, because you're overwriting `c` function.

Answer (score 2):

I borrow the answer from Roman Luštrik for my previous question “How to extract out a partial name as new column name in a data frame”

```
traits <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(names, "\\."), "[[", 3))
```

Comment: You can get rid of `unlist` by using `sapply(strsplit(string, "\\."), "[[", 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `sub`:

```
sub(".*\\.{2}(.+?)\\..*", "\\1", names)
# [1] "flowerdate" "flwrcolor"  "height"     "matdate"
```